# Cannot Remove Document by id params in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I dont know why i cant remove document by id , i use `findByIdAndRemove` method in mongoose but not working
here is my **controller** :

```
const Todos = require('../model/todo');
const Users = require('../model/Users');
module.exports = {
    create(req,res,next){
        const newTodo = new Todos(req.body);
        newTodo.save()
        .then((todo)=>{
            res.send(todo);
        })
        .catch(next);
    },
    read(req,res,next){
        Promise.all([Todos.find({}),Todos.count()])
        .then((result,count) =>{
            res.send(result[0]);
            console.log(result[1]);
        })
        .catch(next);
    },
    searchTodos(req,res,next){
        const todoId = req.params.id;
        Todos.find({_id:todoId})
        .then(result=>{
            res.send(result);
            console.log("To do find: " + result.length);
        })
        .catch(next);
    },
    searchUsers(req,res,next){
        const userName = req.params.name;
        Users.find({name:userName})
        .then(result=>{
            res.send(result);
            console.log("User find count: " + result.length);
        })
        .catch(next);
    },
    removeManyTodos(req,res,next){
        const removeTodos = req.params.text;
        Todos.remove({text:removeTodos})
        .then(result=>{
            res.send(result);
        })
        .catch(next);
    },
    removeOneTodos(req,res,next){
        const TodoId = req.params.id;
        Todos.findByIdAndRemove({_id: new mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id)})
        .then(result=>{
            res.send(result);
        })
        .catch(next);
    }

}
```

and here is my **routes**:

```
const todoController = require('../controller/todoController');
module.exports = (app)=>{
    app.post('/api/todo',todoController.create);
    app.get('/api',todoController.read);
    app.get('/api/todo/:id',todoController.searchTodos);
    app.get('/api/users/:name',todoController.searchUsers);
    app.delete('/api/todo/:text',todoController.removeManyTodos);
    app.delete('/api/todo/:id',todoController.removeOneTodos);
}
```

I dont know what im wrong , why i can not remove it 
The removeMany not working and `removeOneTodos` is not working too. If i try the remove with id like : `remove({_id:"5a012e4079879c2a995bea31"})` it's working but delete by request like `:localhost:3000/api/todo/5a012e4079879c2a995bea31` it's not working ...

Comment: `Todos.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)`. The `{ id: ... }` part is implied by the `byId` naming of the method. From the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) *"Issue a mongodb findAndModify remove command by a document's _id field. findByIdAndRemove(id, ...) is equivalent to findOneAndRemove({ _id: id }, ...)."*

Comment: @NeilLunn I try findByIdAndRemove({_id:req.params.id}) too but its still not working:(

Comment: Becuase you don't use an object. Read the comment again and also read the documentation.

Comment: yeah i do like you said , and why i change app.delete to app.post .. its working ... @NeilLunn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this.
removeOneTodos.remove({
    "_id": req.params.id
   }, function(err, delTodo) {
})
```

Comment: Ok then how are you doing this ???app.delete('/api/todo/:id',todoController.removeOneTodos);

Comment: I think it should be 
app.get('/api/todo/:id',todoController.removeOneTodos);
or post

Comment: ahh , i change it to post and it's working but i still dont know why app.delete it's not working ?

Comment: I think it doesn't support param's.

Comment: I try to find some document to learn more but i cant see... but thank you :D